# Migrating DynaActionForm to Struts2

Tags: struts2, migration, struts, struts-1

While migrating from Struts1 to Struts2, I have encountered `DynaActionForm`. Please provide code snippet as example which will help convert to Struts2. 
Tried lot of google search but no luck!

Comment: https://struts.apache.org/docs/migration-strategies.html

Comment: http://www.infoq.com/news/migrating-struts2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such `DynaActionForm` in Struts2. If you want to set properties dynamically then use a `Map`.

```java
Map<String, Object> dynaActionForm;
//getter and setter here

...

dynaActionForm.put("property1", object1.getProperty1());
dynaActionForm.put("property2", object2.getProperty1());
```

In the JSP you can access this properies

```jsp
<s:property value="dynaActionForm.property1"/>
<s:property value="dynaActionForm.property2"/>
```

Comment: Appreciate your prompt reply. I am new to struts. In my case, DynaAction form is in Filter. Then, Please let me know  1> If the entries in the struts_config.xml needs to be removed. 2> how to replace the code  String password = (String)form.get("password"); in the filter.

Comment: Can you help me with the answer to the above question.

Comment: Before you `get` you should `put` properties to the form, whatever form definition you use you can always have variable number of properties. Make sure you bind them on the page.